# std::is_pointer check with universal references

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a function I've written to check if a given variable is of pointer type:

```
template<typename T>
void CheckIfPointer(T&& value)
{
    static_assert(std::is_pointer<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value, "T must be of pointer type");
}
```

I'm using a universal reference here because I do not want to restrict the value categories that could be passed in. I noticed, however, that in this example:

```
char const* mystr = "Hello World";
CheckIfPointer(mystr);
```

Type `T` is actually `const char *&` (according to clang). So is the `remove_reference` the appropriate solution here? Or is there a cleaner way of checking the actual type, without references getting in the way?

Note that I'm only supporting up to C++14.

Comment: If you want perfect forwarding, you must deal with references.  Also, you should make your function constexpr,

Comment: Funny that void.pointer want to check pointer type :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Type `T` is actually `const char *&` (according to clang).

There is a special rule in template argument deduction that was introduced to permit **perfect-forwarding**. In the context of template argument deduction, `T&&` is not an *rvalue reference* but a *forwarding reference* instead.

If an *lvalue* is passed to a function template taking a *forwarding reference*, the type parameter is deduced as `T&` instead of `T`. This allows *reference collapsing* to take place: `T& &&` becomes `T&`.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

> If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called forwarding reference), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, the type lvalue reference to A is used in place of A for deduction (Note: this is the basis for the action of std::forward Note: in class template argument deduction, template parameter of a class template is never a forwarding reference (since C++17))
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> int f(T&&);       // P is an rvalue reference to cv-unqualified T (forwarding reference)
> template<class T>
> int g(const T&&); // P is an rvalue reference to cv-qualified T (not special)
>
> int main()
> {
>     int i;
>     int n1 = f(i); // argument is lvalue: calls f<int&>(int&) (special case)
>     int n2 = f(0); // argument is not lvalue: calls f<int>(int&&)
>
> //  int n3 = g(i); // error: deduces to g<int>(const int&&), which
>                    // cannot bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue
> }
> ```

---

> So is the remove_reference the appropriate solution here? Or is there a cleaner way of checking the actual type, without references getting in the way?

Yes, `remove_reference` is appropriate here. You might want to use `std::remove_reference_t` to avoid the explicit `typename` and `::type`.

---

Also, why are you passing pointers by *forwarding reference*? Are you sure you don't want to pass *by value* or *by lvalue reference*?

Consider taking a `const T&` instead:

```
template<typename T>
void CheckIfPointer(const T& value)
{
    static_assert(std::is_pointer<T>::value, "T must be of pointer type");
}
```

Comment: Well it may or may not be a pointer, that's the point of my function. I feel like forwarding reference is safer in this regard (i.e. doesn't prohibit value-types, doesn't force copy semantics, etc)

Comment: @void.pointer: ...but you're static asserting that it is a pointer?

Comment: Yeah, in my real-world code this is actually a setter method for "user data" in an event system. The semantics of how this works is very legacy and not ideal, but the rule is that user data cannot be anything but a pointer. So a compiler error should occur if a non-pointer-type is passed, to force the user to correct the type.

Comment: I'm not opposed, I just thought that `T&&` was preferable in a "generic programming" sense. What in your opinion influences the decision between one or the other in this case?

Comment: @void.pointer: you're only reading from `value` and never copying/moving it. There's no reason to take a *forwarding reference*. `const T&` prevents copies, is read-only, and makes your implementation simpler (don't need `remove_reference`).

Comment: I guess my only hold-back in this case is that `const` is a lie, since the value is ultimately stored in a `boost::any` and that value may not be const to allow the receiver of the user data to mutate it. As far as the `Check` is concerned, yes it's const, but the value being checked may not be const in the grander scheme of things.

Comment: The `const` applies only for the duration of the `CheckIfPointer` call. E.g.: `void setter(T&& x){ CheckIfPointer(x); my_x = forward<T>(x); }`.